# Java Jar Looking for Windows SWT Library on Linux

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

A year ago, I created an Eclipse project that was developed on Windows and deployed to Linux. I used SWT, and I was able to get it running on Linux with the appropriate SWT jar. No problems.

Recently, I started a new project with the same MO: develop on Windows, deploy to Linux, use SWT. I used the same project structure as the project that worked, but it won't work on Linux. When I try to run the new project on Linux, it hits me with an UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
no swt-win32-4924r25 in java.library.path
no swt-win32 in java.library.path
Can't load library: /home/hmartin/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32-4924r25.so
Can't load library: /home/hmartin/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-win32.so
```

What looks peculiar to me is that it seems to be looking for the Windows version of the SWT jar, and I don't understand why that could be. I've fiddled with project preferences, build paths, build.xml, manifests, etc.

I do have a manifest that is supposed to tell the application where its SWT library is (in the same directory as the application jar), but I suspect that my project doesn't know it exists. With the working project I made a year ago, I remember being able to have Eclipse generate a manifest file upon export, and that's what I did. With this (broken) project, I am not able to generate a manifest file nor do I have the option of selecting one from the workspace upon export. This time, I just made a manifest file myself, followed the naming conventions, and hoped the magic happened. The magic has not happened.

Help, suggestions, recommendations, etc. are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with a test project and export settings, I discovered that the cause of my problems was one single check box on the JAR export screen: "Export generated class files and resources". I had this box unchecked, which meant that (for some reason) Eclipse wouldn't show me the options to generate or select a manifest. With that box checked and manifest selected, the new project now runs on the target platform.